# Why Firebase CLI evaluates global context on deploying functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli, firebase-tools

My function file has some code in the global context.

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import { initBot } from './bot';

const bot = initBot(process.env.BOT_TOKEN ?? '');

functions.logger.debug('Setting webhook on cold start');
const adminConfig = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG ?? '');

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises
bot.telegram.setWebhook(
  `https://us-central1-${adminConfig.projectId}.cloudfunctions.net/${process.env.K_SERVICE}`
);

// handle all telegram updates with HTTPs trigger
exports.bot = functions
  .runWith({ secrets: ['BOT_TOKEN'], memory: '128MB' })
  .https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
...
```

As [documentation states](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/tips#do_not_start_background_activities:%7E:text=When%20a%20cold%20start%20occurs%2C%20the%20global%20context%20of%20the%20function%20is%20evaluated.),

> When a cold start occurs, the global context of the function is evaluated.

I want to use this feature to run some code on cold start. This approach is taken from the [telegraf.js example](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/blob/be38a91ae5ab8ead572c4539b21e1fa9451c4a18/docs/examples/google-cloud-function.ts#L14).

However, when I'm trying to deploy the function, Firebase CLI evaluates the global context, and the code throws an error due to lack of environment variable.

[image: error]

**Questions:**

1. Why does CLI evaluate the global context which obviously leads to errors due to the lack of proper environment?
2. Is there any way to avoid this?
3. Is it a proper understanding of the recommendations on the above mentioned documentation page that developers are encouraged to do some cold-start computation in the global context of the function module? Are there any documented restrictions?

Comment: I do not think your token is correctly implemented using `runWith`. Can you define your environment variable following [this documentation][1], and try it again?


  [1]: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#env-variables

Comment: I was thoroughly referring exactly this documentation while investigating the issue myself. I'm using the new and recommended [Environment variables](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#env-variables) approach along with the [Secrects section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#secret-manager). However the issue persists even if not using secrets, just an environment var. *But!* The question is about different. Why does deployment fail due to evaluation of the code?